# ¿SSH me funcionará si a mi servidor solo puedo entrar desde mi red local?

Tags: servidor, ssh, lamp

Tengo un servidor al cual si puedo ingresar desde otros dispositivos utilizando una ip, pero solo puedo acceder desde mi red local, es decir, entro remotamente local.
Y mi pregunta es si ¿podré acceder a mi servidor con SSH, pese a esta situación?

Comment: probá con `ssh -vvv usuario@ip` a ver que te dice

Comment: En la máquina donde tengo instalado el servidor?